# How to print array of element which is store in pointer to an array and this pointer to an array is store in array of pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

Hi How to print array of element which is sotre in pointer to an array and this pointer to an array is store in array of pointer?

```
/* note- ptoa is pointer to an array
aofp is array of pointer */

#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
     int i;
     int arr[3] = {1,2,3};   // integer array with 3 integers
     int (*ptoa)[3];         // ponter to an array
     ptoa = &arr;            // here i am storing 3 integer
                             // to ponter to an array
     int *aofp[1];           // this is array of pointer

     aofp[1] = ptoa;         // here i am sotring pointer to an array

     /* here i am trying to print all element of arr[3]
        using aofp i.e array of pointer*/

     for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
         printf("%d", **aofp[i]);     // i know this is invalid 
         //please help me i want print all
         //element of arr i.e 1,2,3 using aofp?
}
```

Comment: `aofp[1]=ptoa` invokes UB both due to invalid aliasing and exceeding the array boundaries of `aofp` (its an array of [1], and therefore only indexible by `aofp[0]`) (**Edit**: see comment from @Jashaszun =P)

Comment: If you want `aofp[1]=ptoa;` to work, then `aofp` has to be declared like this: `int ((*aofp)[3])[2]` (**Edit** basically what @WhozCraig said.)

Comment: @Jashaszun still its not working can u please post small hint code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The Problem

> ```
> int *aofp[1]; // this is array of pointer
> ```

`aofp` is a one-element array of **pointer to int**.

> ```
> aofp[1]=ptoa;   // here i am sotring pointer to an array
> ```

Here you are trying to assign a **pointer to array of int** to `aofp`. These are not compatible types. Also, element `[1]` doesn't exist. You have two options here, possibly more:

#### Option 1

You need to declare `aofp` with the correct type, and access element `[0]`:

```
int (*aofp[1])[3];
aofp[0]=ptoa;

for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  printf("%d",(*aofp[0])[i]);
putchar ('\n');
```

The parenthesis in the declaration of `aofp` are important, because `int *aofp[1][3]` would be an **array-of-array-of-pointers**, rather than an **array-of-pointers-to-array**. Accessing the values of the array uses the same syntax as the declaration. Retrieve element `[0]` of the array of pointers, dereference the pointer (`*`), and retrieve element `[i]` of the array of ints.

However, all this is unnecessarily convoluted, because a one-element array of pointers is pretty much the same as a single pointer. You might as well declare `aofp` as a **pointer to array of int**:

```
int (*aofp)[3];
```

And now we see that the type of `aofp` is exactly the same as that of `ptoa`. You could just as well skip `aofp` and print out the array pointed at by `ptoa` directly:

```
for (i=0;i<3;i++)
  printf("%d",(*ptoa)[i]);
putchar ('\n');
```

Of course, `aofp` might be declared to have more than one element at a later time.

#### Option 2

You need to assign a **pointer-to-int** to `aofp[0]`. Since `ptoa` is a **pointer-to-array-of-int**, dereferencing it results in a **pointer to** the first element of the **int** array. (Actually the result is an expression of type **array-of-int**, but you can't have array values in C, so it is immediately converted to a **pointer-to-int**.)

```
int *aofp[1];

aofp[0] = *ptoa;

for (i=0;i<3;i++)
  printf("%d",aofp[0][i]);
putchar ('\n');
```

And, like the previous example, a single-element array is rather useless. You might as well write:

```
int *aofp;

aofp = *ptoa;

for (i=0;i<3;i++)
  printf("%d",aofp[i]);
putchar ('\n');
```

Or just print out `arr[i]` directly.

#### Final note

You may have noticed that I have added a `putchar ('\n')` call at the end. The reason for this is that a C program might not produce any visible result unless it ends with a new-line.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, you start off all good, except for the typing mistakes in comments maybe; but then you start doing invalid actions after some point, specifically at the line:

```
int *aofp[1];
```

This itself is all good actually. You are properly declaring a variable called `aofp` here, as an array of pointers to integers with a single element, with this statement. However, with the next line:

```
aofp[1]=ptoa;
```

It appears that you did not really want to declare that as an array of *pointers to integers* with a single element, but rather as an array of *pointers to arrays of integers with three elements* with a single element. This is because, the latter italicised thing is exactly what `ptoa` is of.

Another important thing here is that arrays in C are zero-based, which means that if you declare an array with the size denoted within square-brackets during declaration, the elements are indexed from `[0]` to `[size - 1]`, so you should be making the assignment like:

```
aofp[0]=ptoa;
```

But this is only after declaring the `aofp` properly as I've mentioned.

The following code would be the thoroughly corrected version of your code, without changing the way you're handling the job:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main( )
{
    int i;
    int arr[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int(*ptoa)[3];
    ptoa = &arr;

    // previously was: int *aofp[1];
    int(*aofp[1])[3];   // aofp is declared as an
 /*  1  2     3   4  */ // array of 1   (3)
                        // pointer to   (2)
                        // array of 3   (4)
                        // integers     (1)

    // previously was: aofp[1] = ptoa;
    aofp[0] = ptoa;

    for (i = 0; i<3; i++)
        // previously was: printf("%d", **aofp[i]);
        printf("%d", (*aofp[0])[i]);

    return 0;   // should be there in C
}
```

For a code that compiles without warnings/errors, although it might be violating some rules, the following minimal changes could be done:

1. At your own risk.
2. `aofp[1]=ptoa;` to `aofp[0] = (int *) ptoa;`
3. `**aofp[i]` inside printf to `(*((int (*)[3]) aofp[0]))[i]`

Should do it, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 1):

this is exactly what you want:

```
int main()
{
     int i;
     int arr[3]={1,2,3};// integer array with 3 integers
     int *ptoa = arr;// ponter to an array
     int *aofp[1]; // this is array of pointer
     aofp[0]=ptoa;   // here i am sotring pointer to an array

     for(i=0;i<3;i++)
         printf("%d",*aofp[0]+i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it this what you want to do (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f342849a8018de37)?

```
/* note- ptoa is pointer to an array
aofp is array of pointer */

#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int i;
     int arr[3]={1,2,3};    // integer array with 3 integers
     int* ptoa = arr;       // pointer to an array

     int* aofp[3];          // this is array of pointer
     aofp[0] = ptoa;        // here i am storing pointer to an element of array
     aofp[1] = ptoa+1;      // here i am storing pointer to an element of array
     aofp[2] = ptoa+2;      // here i am storing pointer to an element of array

     /* here i am trying to print all element of arr[3]
        using aofp i.e array of pointer*/

     for(i=0;i<3;i++)
         printf("%d", *aofp[i]);  
}
```

Comment: pointer to an array will increment by 12 byte cause it is pointing to 3 element arr[3] i m confused here?